# ms sync out of memory exception

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm trying to sync sql server database having size > 4GB. Getting Out of memory exception. Tried with MemoryDataCacheSize  & ApplicationTransactionSize . No success. The code is given here.

```
    public static long BatchSize = 500000;
    public static uint MemorySize = 4000000000;
    public void Sync(ServerSyncHelper server)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = DBConnection;
            SqlConnection serverConn = server.DBConnection;
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
            var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(ScopeName, clientConn);
            localProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = MemorySize;
            localProvider.ApplicationTransactionSize = BatchSize;
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
            var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(server.ScopeName, serverConn);

            remoteProvider.ApplicationTransactionSize = BatchSize;
            remoteProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = MemorySize;
            remoteProvider.ChangesApplied += new EventHandler<DbChangesAppliedEventArgs>(RemoteProvider_ChangesApplied);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(ApplyChangeFailed);
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
            LogWriter.Write("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            LogWriter.Write("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            LogWriter.Write("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running as 32-bit?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that a 32-bit value maxes out at 4GB (2^2 * 2^30). Not sure if your uint MemorySize is running into that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your process is trying to allocate too much memory (this is controlled by the MemoryDataCacheSize). [Look here for more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx) on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I already tried with the amount given in the link for BatchSize and MemoryDataCacheSize. But no hope!